# Replace part of string in a link Javascript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have the following link:

`/v1/catalogue/folders/{catalogueId:[0-9]+}/translations/{translationId:[0-9]+}/`

and the following data:

```
catalogueId: 31
translationId: 4
```

Now I'd like to change the part between the curly brackets with the value of the data-object. So the link needs to look like this:

`/v1/catalogue/folders/31/translations/4/`

Is there a way in Javascript to accoomplish this? If yes, what is that way?

Comment: When you made an attempt, what went wrong? I'd suggest taking a look at [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), as a hint. But first, is that link in your browser's address bar (are you *on* the page that link represents), or is it a string somewhere else in your document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see example below

```js
var data = {
  catalogueId: 31,
  translationId: 4,
};

var url = $('#mylink').attr('href');
for(var key in data) {
  var regex = new RegExp('{' + key + '[^}]*}', 'g');
  console.log(regex);
  url = url.replace(regex, data[key]);
}
console.log(url);
$('#mylink').attr('href', url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="mylink" href="/v1/catalogue/folders/{catalogueId:[0-9]+}/translations/{translationId:[0-9]+}/">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the options:

```
const regex = /\{(.*?)\}/g
const url = "/v1/catalogue/folders/{catalogueId:[0-9]+}/translations/{translationId:[0-9]+}/"
const replacements = { catalogueId: 19, translationId: 20 } 

const result = url.replace(regex, function(_, segment) {
  return replacements[ segment.split(':')[0] ];
});
```

Comment: Clean and concise. Edited to remove some of the parametric noise (sorry if it bothered)